Query performance on selecting date range with 'BETWEEN' vs Inequality
I was wondering if it using 'BETWEEN' is faster than the inequality for date range.
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= DATE '2024-07-01'
  AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE <= DATE '2024-07-05'

or
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2024-07-01'
                           AND DATE '2024-07-05'

I tried the explain plan but it wasn't that different between these two operations. Your opinions are greatly appreciated.
There weren't enough data in my test instance so I only tested with small rows of data, but would like to see how the performance is when the data size grows.

Note: In Oracle, a DATE always has both date and time components and neither option in the question will return values between 2024-07-05 00:00:01 and 2024-07-05 23:59:59. If you want all times from the final day then you want to use WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= DATE '2024-07-01' AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE < DATE '2024-07-06'.

No, there's no difference.

Summary: You can check the EXPLAIN PLANs and see that there is no difference.

You can check the EXPLAIN PLAN for the two queries:
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  last_update_date DATE
);

Then:
EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = 'gte_lte' FOR
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= DATE '2024-07-01'
AND    LAST_UPDATE_DATE <= DATE '2024-07-05'

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY(statement_id=>'gte_lte'));

Outputs:
Plan hash value: 3383972830
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |            |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_NAME |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("LAST_UPDATE_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2024-07-01 00:00:00',
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "LAST_UPDATE_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2024-07-05
              00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)

and:
EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = 'between' FOR
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  LAST_UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2024-07-01'
                            AND DATE '2024-07-05'

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY(statement_id=>'between'));

Outputs:
Plan hash value: 3383972830
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |            |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_NAME |     1 |    22 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("LAST_UPDATE_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2024-07-01 00:00:00',
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "LAST_UPDATE_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2024-07-05
              00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)

You can see that the BETWEEN filter is converted to >=/<= in the execution plan and the two queries are identical.
fiddle

However
If you want to return all date values on the days 2024-07-01 through 2024-07-05 then you need to know that a DATE in Oracle has both date and time components (some client applications may default to not showing the time component - but that does not mean it does not exist) and DATE '2024-07-05 is the date at midnight (i.e. 2024-07-05 00:00:00). If your time components of the DATEs in the table are non-midnight then you want to use:
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= DATE '2024-07-01'
AND    LAST_UPDATE_DATE <  DATE '2024-07-06' -- Use < and increase the upper bound by 1

Otherwise you will exclude values between 2024-07-05 00:00:01 and 2024-07-05 23:59:59.

Yes, include then exclude principle is the main reason not to use BETWEEN with Date and Time, +1
